# how to use libxml2 to parse data from GInputStream (GLibGIO/GVFS)?

Tags: stream, gtk, libxml2, glib, gio

In a GTK application, I'm using `xmlParseFile()` from libxml2. However, that function can only read local files. How can I instead make it use the GIO framework, so that it can read remote files as well?

The simplest way is probably to use something like `g_file_load_contents()` to read the entire file into memory, then call `xmlParseMemory()` to parse that. However, I'm looking for a "nicer" solution which ideally streams the data (to avoid keeping the entire data in memory); possibly by connecting a `GInputStream` to libxml2?

Code examples welcome. I would guess this is a common use case, so collecting an exhaustive list of good implementations here might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

There are instructions (with code examples) on the libxml2 website about how to parse XML data chunk by chunk from a file: http://xmlsoft.org/library.html#Invoking1

If you wanted to use `GInputStream` then you could use `g_input_stream_read()` to feed chunks to `xmlParseChunk()` in the same manner as the example program in the libxml2 documentation.